# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred when using a guard statement to unwrap a generic function

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to use a generic modular function within Combine, but I'm getting the error that generic could not be inferred.

```swift
func foo<T>(data: T) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, MyError> {
    
}

func bar<T>(data: T) -> AnyPublisher<String, MyError> {
    Deferred { [weak self] () -> AnyPublisher<Bool, MyError> in
        guard let foo = self?.foo else { // error here
            return Fail(error: .someError)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        return foo(data)
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    .flatMap { [weak self] (value) -> AnyPublisher<String, MyError> in
        Future<String, MyError> { [weak self] promise in
            // do something with the returned value 
            promise(.success("Success"))
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

enum MyError: Error {
    case someError
}
```

I'm getting the error when I'm trying to unwrap a function using a guard statement. `T` doesn't have constraints because it could be multiple disparate types like `Data` or `UIImage` which gets type checked within the `foo` function.

Comment: Try breaking it into two steps. First, conditionally unwrap `self` back to a non-optional. Then compare `foo`

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't think the Optional has anything to do with the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a problem like this, *simplify*. We can reduce the phenomenon to a very simple case:

```
class MyClass {
    func foo<T>(data: T) -> Void { }
    func bar<T>(data: T) -> Void {
        let foo = self.foo // error
    }
}
```

Now, the first thing to realize is that you have two separate T placeholders. You say T with regard to `foo` and with regard to `bar`, but they have no relation to one another. We can rewrite more clearly:

```
class MyClass {
    func foo<FooDataType>(data: FooDataType) -> Void { }
    func bar<BarDataType>(data: BarDataType) -> Void {
        let foo = self.foo // error: Generic parameter 'FooDataType' could not be inferred
    }
}
```

Now it's clear what the problem is, because we know *which* placeholder the compiler is having trouble with. When you look at it that way, you realize that FooDataType is entirely confined to `foo`. How would `bar` know what type this is going to be?

If your idea is that they should be the *same* type, then say so. Make the *class* the generic, not the individual functions:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    func foo(data: T) -> Void { }
    func bar(data: T) -> Void {
        let foo = self.foo // fine
    }
}
```